# delete from one object those entries matching another object based off string id

Tags: jq

So, given two files with JSON data from the same source type. The JSON objects look something like:

file1:

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "2",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "6",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "61",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "baz"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "63",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "qux"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

file2:

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "61",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "baz"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "63",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "qux"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to remove objects in the array in the first file with the matching IDs in the second file so that the resultant output would be:

```json
[
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "2",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "foo"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "id": "6",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "stuff": "bar"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I've tried a bunch of ways to accomplish this, but I haven't found a proper solution yet.

A couple of attempts have been various permutations of the following with accompanying errors:

```bash
jq -n --argfile src /var/tmp/w-src.json --argfile dst /var/tmp/w-dst.json '
$dst
| [.data[].id] as $ids
| $src
| .data | map(select(.id | in($ids[])))

jq: error: select/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 5:
| .data | map($ids | map(select .id == .))                         
jq: 1 compile error
```

```bash
jq -n --argfile src /var/tmp/w-src.json --argfile dst /var/tmp/w-dst.json '
$dst
| [.data[].id] as $ids
| $src
| .data[] | select(.id | in($ids[]))
'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot check whether string has a string key
```

Ideally it would be super cool to do some kind of operation like:

```
$src.data[] - $dst.data[]
```

(kinda Ruby-ish like would be cool) and I admit, I haven't tried this but I will for kicks and giggles.

I'm trying not to have to use a function and I want to accomplish this using `jq`. I'm probably not too far off, but I'm at a loss. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile a list of IDs from the second file using `input`, check against it using `IN`, and either use `del` to delete the matching, or `map` to keep those that do `not` match:

```bash
jq '
  (input | map(.data.id)) as $del | del(.[] | select(IN(.data.id; $del[])))
' file1.json file2.json
```

or

```bash
jq '
  (input | map(.data.id)) as $del | map(select(IN(.data.id; $del[]) | not))
' file1.json file2.json
```

---

If you can assert that objects with identical IDs also are identical in their other parts, and you don't have many items (because it's costly), you can even just subtract the second file from the first:

```bash
jq '. - input' file1.json file2.json
```

Comment: Thank you! My data sets are small, so the last option works OK for me now. Good stuff.